# how to insert <?php echo $image;?> in <img src=""> tag

Tags: php, image, echo

i'm trying to modify my PHP code so that i can insert html tag just inside it.the original code was:

```
<?php 
if( $image ){
?>
<a class="product_image image-woo" href="<?php echo $product_url;?>">
    <?php echo $image;?>
</a>
<?php } ?>
```

now,i,ve edited in this way:

```
<?php 
if( $image ){
?>
<img data-src="<?php echo $image;?>" class="something">
<?php } ?>
```

What,s wrong about?

Comment: `<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>">` and check first what $image returns image link or something else

Comment: are you getting whole image tag in $image

Comment: it returns some pictures properly,but for some of them it returns in inspector:` <img  src="<img width=" 250"="" height="220"> ""> ` @mario

Comment: put `var_dump($image);` you will get all data from $image variable, u must have something like image_name.jpg

Comment: sorryو I'm not sure that I understand your mean,but yes,it's getting whole images of loops @afsar

Comment: i guess your code is trying to put image tag inside img src attribute. For src you will need image url, your $image contains image url with img tag

Comment: thank you.but unfortunately i'm newbie with php,where should i put `var_dubp($image)`

Comment: yes,exactly,how can i get image url only and thereby put it in the src? @Jabs

Comment: @Hamihamidd after this line `if( $image ){`

Comment: see my answer though it is not proper way but it will work for your code

Comment: @Mario wonderful.thank u .got solved.but there is a problem.in inspector i see two image codes which have overlapped together.[screenshot](http://www.upsara.com/images/jgy3_skfhkdfjghh.png)

Comment: @Jabs yes,you right.but i'm not sure how can i get image url and put it on src

Comment: it mixing `src=""` and `srcset=""` i think its a problem when u insert images into database probably. u will need to change this in database table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if($image) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($image);
    $imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($imgs as $img) { ?>
        <img data-src="<?php echo $img->getAttribute("src");?>" class="something"/>
    <?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: i did it.everything seems ok in inspector.but no image appeard

Comment: then change data-src to src

Comment: thank u very much.it solved my problem.but an amazing problem arose.the picture that have non-Latin character in their names do not appear.

Comment: indeed,their links in inspector show weird character

Answer (score 1):

Its `src` not `data-src`

```
<?php 
 if( $image ){
?>
 <img src="<?php echo $image;?>" class="something">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: yes,but i want to build a lazy load image via data strings

Comment: @Hamihamidd I hope you are using this - https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload and they use data-original and hope that you have initialized it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is src not data-src
and you need to echo like this

```
<?php 
if( $image ){

echo "<img src= '$image' class='something'>";
 } ?>
```

Comment: yes,but i want to build a lazy load image via data strings